# Python regionprops sci-kit image

Tags: image, image-processing

I am using sci-kit image to get the "regionprops" of a segmented image. I then wish to replace each of the segment labels with their corresponding statistic (e.g eccentricity).

```
from skimage import segmentation
from skimage.measure import regionprops

#a segmented image
labels = segmentation.slic(img1, compactness=10, n_segments=200)
propimage = labels
#props loop
for region in regionprops(labels1, properties ='eccentricity') :
    eccentricity = region.eccentricity 
    propimage[propimage==region] = eccentricity
```

This runs, but the propimage values do not change from their original labels

I have also tried:

```
for i in range(0,max(labels)):
     prop = regions[i].eccentricity #the way to cal a single prop
     propimage[i]= prop
```

This delivers this error
ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

I am a recent migrant from matlab where I have implemented this, but the data structures used are completely different.

Can any one help me with this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use ndimage from scipy : the sum() function can operate using your label array.

```
from scipy import ndimage as nd
sizes = nd.sum(label_file[0]>0, labels=label_file[0], index=np.arange(0,label_file[1])
```

You can then evaluate the distribution with numpy.histogram and so on.